# Search for multi word in search engin in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I stuck in this problem for 2 days and hope you can help me !
its about my search engine, I let the user enter some keyword sperated by space or comma and if they match the keyword in my table; it will display the row of table that contain the exact keyword, try this one and no responding :

```
$words = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword']);
if(empty($words)){
redirect("welcome.php?error=search_empty");
}
$sql="SELECT * FROM DataTable
 WHERE MATCH (keyword)
 AGAINST ('{$words}' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)";
$results=mysql_query($sql,$connection);
if(!$results){
redirect("errors/error_db.html");
}
else if($results){
$rows = array();
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
 echo" <tr><td>".$row['Name']."</td><td>".$row['Link']."
 </td><td>".$row['ISSN']."</td><td>".$row['FactorValue']."
 </td><td>".$row['Country']."</td><td>".$row['NoIssuesyear']."
 </td><td>".$row['FirstIssues']."</td></tr>" ;  
 }
 H}
```

Comment: It's a typo `while($rows` <<< plural. `$row` <<< singular and is off-topic.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  ok ok thank you i get it

Answer (score 0):

For one you have:

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

when you should have

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC))
```

Answer (score 0):

As written by Fred, there is a typo. You are filling `$rows` variable but then accessing `$row`. Also the defining $rows as empty array before the loop is not needed. I see also typo of "H" at the end but this is (I guess) only result of posting here on stackoverflow.

Afterall, this is the working code:

```js
$words = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword']);
if (empty($words)) {
  redirect("welcome.php?error=search_empty");
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM DataTable
 WHERE MATCH (keyword)
 AGAINST ('{$words}' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)";
$results = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
if (!$results) {
  redirect("errors/error_db.html");
} else if ($results) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo " <tr><td>".$row['Name']."</td><td>".$row['Link'].
    "</td><td>".$row['ISSN']."</td><td>".$row['FactorValue'].
    "</td><td>".$row['Country']."</td><td>".$row['NoIssuesyear'].
    "</td><td>".$row['FirstIssues']."</td></tr>";
  }
}
```

Comment: it's print no thing :( what's wrong ! for more info: I want to compare the keyword that the user enter with the all keyword in one row (like the user write " IT,strategies" and the code search in the field "IT,process,strategies" .